# $_SESSION variable not setting in AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

I wrote this call for user authentication:

```
$( '.sign-in' ).click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var logincall = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../snippets/auth.php",
        data: { username: $('#id_email').val(), password:   $('#id_password').val() }
    });
    logincall.done(function( result ) {
        alert( 'finished: ' + result );
        if( result == 'valid' ) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            $( '.warning' ).toggleClass('hidden');
        }
    });
    logincall.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
});
```

and here's the auth.php function

```
if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if( $result['COUNT(*)'] !== 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true; //this sets
        $query = "SELECT id, level FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $result['id']; //this DOES NOT set
        $_SESSION['lvl'] = $result['level']; //this DOES NOT set
        echo json_encode('valid');
    } else {
        echo json_encode('invalid');
    }
}
```

The odd thing is, if I navigate directly to

```
myurl.com/snippets/auth.php?username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

it DOES set the other two session variables, but I can never get `index.php` to pick them up.

I even added that refresh line to it to ensure it *could* pick them up, and it gets `$_SESSION['logged']` just fine, but not `['uid']` or `['level']`

Comment: You should not send authentication details in $_GET. Use $_POST instead. You should not use md5 to hash a password. Use password_hash instead. Also, it is good practice to use bound parameters in your queries.

Comment: did you remember to `session_start()` everywhere?

Comment: login code should definitely use POST never GET

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I just have a few tips.  *a)* Don't send the password via the URL query (GET), *b)* You can use an object for the `data` in `$.ajax` like so: `$.ajax({ data: {username: ''} });`.

Comment: A few more tips: *c)* Your PHP code is very unsafe.  ***Never*** assume user-inputted data is safe and never concatenate variables into an SQL query.  What would happen if I decided to login as `admin' AND 1=1; -- `?  You should use prepared statements, see: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html, *d)* While you *can* use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode a string, you should really be encoding an array or object.  `json_encode(array('status' => 'valid'))`.  Then in your AJAX callback do: `if( result.status == 'valid' )`.

Comment: Couple more tips: *e)* Don't use `md5` for passwords.  Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify), *f)* There's no reason to query `member` twice.  Just do `SELECT id, level FROM member ...` and check if that returns any rows.  It's wasteful to call `SELECT COUNT(*)` first here.

Comment: Yeah I've got session_start(); in each file. I'm using md5 while testing because there's no signup form yet. Thanks for the advice on post vs. get, I'll rewrite those portions. I still have no idea why those two session vars aren't saving tho.

Comment: And now, with those small changes, it's working fine. Thanks all!